# Replace a value of json

Tags: linux, awk, sed, json, jq

I have a big json file, I have put two sections of that file below.

```
[
      {
        "description": null,
        "icmp-options": null,
        "is-stateless": false,
        "protocol": "17",
        "source": "1.0.0.0/8",
        "source-type": "CIDR_BLOCK",
        "tcp-options": null,
        "udp-options": {
          "destination-port-range": null,
          "source-port-range": {
            "max": 1433,
            "min": 521
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "description": null,
        "icmp-options": null,
        "is-stateless": false,
        "protocol": "17",
        "source": "1.0.0.0/8",
        "source-type": "CIDR_BLOCK",
        "tcp-options": null,
        "udp-options": {
          "destination-port-range": null,
          "source-port-range": {
            "max": 1899,
            "min": 1435
          }
        }
      }
]
```

I want to change the destination-port-range value as below

```
  "destination-port-range": {
    "max": 100,
    "min": 90
  },
```

As the json file is very big, can someone help me how can this be done using jq or any other method?

Comment: Do you want to change it in both records? And what is your own approach?

Comment: All the record I would say

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the JSON processing tool `jq` to add the `min` and `max` values taken from the command line:

```bash
jq --argjson min 90 --argjson max 100 \
    'map(."udp-options"."destination-port-range" = $ARGS.named)' file
```

By using the `--argjson` options like this, we create an internal variable `$ARGS`, whose `named` key will be the object `{"min":90,"max":100}`.  I'm using `--argjson` instead of `--arg` as the latter would import the values as *strings*.

The expression `."udp-options"."destination-port-range" = $ARGS.named` assigns this object to the `destinaton-port-range` sub-object of `udp-options`,  and we use `map()` to apply this to all array elements in the input.  The key names have to be quoted as they contain dashes.

The result, given the data in the question, will be the equivalent of this:

```json
[
   {
      "description": null,
      "icmp-options": null,
      "is-stateless": false,
      "protocol": "17",
      "source": "1.0.0.0/8",
      "source-type": "CIDR_BLOCK",
      "tcp-options": null,
      "udp-options": {
         "destination-port-range": { "max": 100, "min": 90 },
         "source-port-range": { "max": 1433, "min": 521 }
      }
   },
   {
      "description": null,
      "icmp-options": null,
      "is-stateless": false,
      "protocol": "17",
      "source": "1.0.0.0/8",
      "source-type": "CIDR_BLOCK",
      "tcp-options": null,
      "udp-options": {
         "destination-port-range": { "max": 100, "min": 90 },
         "source-port-range": { "max": 1899, "min": 1435 }
      }
   }
]
```

Would you only want to update the value if there is no pre-existing non-null (or non-false) value, use the following expression instead:

```
map(."udp-options"."destination-port-range" |=  (. // $ARGS.named))
```

This updates the value to the same as the current value unless it is *false* or *null*, in which case the new data is used.

Comment: Thanks this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

with sed:

```bash
sed '/^\s*"destination-port-range": null,/s/null,/{\n"max": 100,\n"min": 90\n},/' data_file
```